# Datewise data fetching with laravel and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a data in the database with 2 table called registrations, ssi_tracks i a need to show registrations table data based on track_first_status.I need to filter datas by datewise and show it on the datatable

Controller file with custom function

```
public function datewise(Request $request, $data_end, $data_start){


      $data_start->$request->input('start_date');
      $data_end->$request->input('end_date');


     $datewise=DB::table('registrations')
          ->join('ssi_tracks', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'ssi_tracks.registration_id')
          ->select('address', 'model', 'chassis', 'delivery_date')
          ->where([["ssi_tracks.track_first_status", "=", 0]])
          ->whereBetween('created_at',[$data_start, $data_end])
          ->get();

      $output = "";
      $count = 1;
      foreach ($datewise as  $reg) {

          $output .= '<tr>' .
              '<td>' . $count++ . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->address . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->model . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->chassis . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->delivery_date . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded button">Call Customer
                                                    </button>'. '</td>' .

              '</tr>';


      }
      return response()->json($output);
}
```

Ajax Function

```
<script>

        $(function () {
            $("#start_date").datepicker();
            $("#end_date").datepicker();
        });
        $('#filter').click(function () {
            let start_date = $('#start_date').val();
            let end_date = $('#end_date').val();
            if (start_date !== '' && end_date !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url("date")}}",
                    method: "get",
                    data: {
                        start_date: start_date,
                        end_date: end_date
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
//                        $('#listdetails').html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please Select Date");
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

index File contains datewise input type

```
 <label>From
                                </label> <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control"
                                                style="width:150px;">
                                <label>To</label> <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control"
                                                         style="width:150px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" id="filter" name="filter" >Filter</button>
```

Comment: $data_start, $data_end format of your db and datepicker is same right?

Comment: yes it is same @Nirali

Comment: Are you getting data in $datewise ??

Comment: No really... there error in whereBetween('created_at',[$data_start, $data_end])  @Nirali

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ssi\app\Http\Controllers\SsiTrackController.php on line 24 and at least 2 expected  @Nirali

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169666/discussion-between-abhijith-and-nirali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
public function datewise(Request $request){

      $data_start = $request->input('start_date');
      $data_end = $request->input('end_date');


     $datewise=DB::table('registrations')
          ->join('ssi_tracks', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'ssi_tracks.registration_id')
          ->select('address', 'model', 'chassis', 'delivery_date')
          ->where([["ssi_tracks.track_first_status", "=", 0]])
          ->whereBetween('created_at',[$data_start, $data_end])
          ->get();

      $output = "";
      $count = 1;
      foreach ($datewise as  $reg) {

          $output .= '<tr>' .
              '<td>' . $count++ . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->address . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->model . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->chassis . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . $reg->delivery_date . '</td>' .
              '<td>' . '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded button">Call Customer
                                                    </button>'. '</td>' .

              '</tr>';


      }
      return response()->json($output);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much same but if change objects it will throws error variables not declared @Chirag Patel

Comment: you have defined variables like this `$data_start->$request->input('start_date');
      $data_end->$request->input('end_date');` that i have changed. Now what is the error?

Comment: it is same like in the question @Chirag Patel